# Filter robot out of laser scan

Tags: ros, laser-filters, laserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to filter out the laser points that hit my robot. There are points above and below the scanner (green thing) that should be removed. I'm thinking I'm supposed to use [LaserScanAngularBoundsFilter](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/laser_filters/html/classlaser__filters_1_1LaserScanAngularBoundsFilter.html) but am not sure.

[image: Points to be filtered]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10821/filter-robot-out-of-laser-scan/) by [patrick_hammer](https://answers.ros.org/users/465/patrick_hammer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 283 on 2011-08-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a [robot_self_filter](http://www.ros.org/wiki/robot_self_filter) package that allows you to filter robot links from your sensor data based on URDF description of the robot.

---

Originally posted by [arebgun](https://answers.ros.org/users/18/arebgun/) with karma: 2121 on 2011-08-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the Turtlebot applications, there is a node called turtlebot_laser that filters out all points within the radius of your base. This is how Willow solved it for the Turtlebot. The only pointer I can give is directly to the [code](https://kforge.ros.org/turtlebot/turtlebot_apps/file/5df026635923/turtlebot_laser) as the wiki is not updated.

---

Originally posted by [cmansley](https://answers.ros.org/users/803/cmansley/) with karma: 198 on 2011-08-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2